# Cross-referencing an equation

Tags: cross-referencing, equations

So far I've always used non-labeled alignments with `align*`, but I think it's time for a small change. How do I refer to an alignment after creating it? I tried searching similar topics but I didn't find them here. I am using `article` document class.

Also, does equation behave and work similarly to `align`? And how would you refer to an equation number (same situation as with `align`)?

Comment: You can simple use `\begin{align}x+y\label{eq:1}\end{align}` and later use `\ref{eq:1}` or `\eqref{eq:1}` to reference to the equation.

Comment: You can put one label on each line and refer to a particular equation. You can take a look at this pdf [link](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) which gives great examples and a documentation of the amsmath package (from which align comes).

Comment: @MarcoDaniel -- even if the output looks the same, if there's only one line to the display, `equation` is preferable to `align`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your question is more a general question about labeling and referencing equations.

I think one great introduction is the mathmode of Herbert Voss. It's available at CTAN.

[mathmode at CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode)

In the linked document you will find an extra sub section about *Labels*. It is introduced by:

> Every numbered equation can have a label to which a reference is
>   possible.
>
> - There is one restriction for the label names, they cannot include one of 
>     LaTeX’s 8 command characters.
> - The label names are replaced by the equation number.

---

**Update**

The following point was mentioned by Mico:

> It may be useful to note that in addition to the eight "basic" special
>   characters that can't be used inside labels, users should also refrain
>   from using
>
> 1. commas if the plan on using the cleveref package or
> 2. any characters that have special meanings for various languages
>      supported by the babel package (such as : in babel/French).

---

The environment `equation` doesn't allow any line breaks. So the syntax will be:

```
\begin{equation}
 a^2+b^2=c^2\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
```

The environment `align` allows line breaks and so every line can get a label.

```
\begin{align}
  x^2+y^2&=2r^2 \label{eq:1} \\
  d^2+h^2&=4r^2 \label{eq:2}
\end{align}
```

To reference to a given label you can use the standard command `\ref` or any other reference command provided by some packages. I like to use `\eqref` to reference to equations.

Here a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 a^2+b^2=c^2\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
Text \eqref{eq:1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please add an alignment point to `align`? Or use `gather` for that purpose: I believe that `amsmath` environment must not be abused, even if the result is similar. Actually your `align` needs much more work than `gather` for producing essentially the same output.

Comment: @egreg: I added an alignment point. I don't think that this question needs an introduction to ams environments ;-). Or should I add one?

Comment: I believe that these comments will suffice.

Comment: It may be useful to note that in addition to the eight "basic" special characters that can't be used inside labels, users should also refrain from using (i) commas if the plan on using the `cleveref` package or (ii) any characters that have special meanings for various languages supported by the `babel` package (such as `:` in babel/French).

Comment: @Mico: I think this should be added by the author of `mathmode`. Of course I will take your comment (i hope it's ok) and update my answer.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I agree! Yes, and do feel free to add these tidbits of information to your answer as well.

Comment: some info: [eqref is not a robust command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61778/15717) and [short-math-guide](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

For `align` and equation numbering you might be also interested in using `align` together with `subequations`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:1}
\begin{align} 
 a^2+b^2=c^2\label{eq:1a} \\
 a^2+b^2=c^2\label{eq:1b} 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
Text \eqref{eq:1}, \eqref{eq:1a}, \eqref{eq:1b}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you're willing to use the `cleveref` package, that coss-referencing command can be stated more succinctly as `\cref{eq:1a,eq:1b}`, which will generate `equations (1.a) and (1.b)`.