# eqref in captions with mathtools

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, amsmath

I've now tried `mathtools` for the first time, for the sake of `showonlyrefs`. It works fine, except if I put an `\eqref` command into a figure caption, in which case I get:

```
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
! Paragraph ended before \@caption was complete.
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true,showmanualtags=true} % do not number unreferenced equations
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}\label{eq:EVE-HEH}
    x
  \end{equation}
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{See eigenvalue equation \eqref{eq:EVE-HEH}.}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

What do I do wrong?

**Update:** Found [here](http://matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/printtopic.php?topic=152873) that `\protect` before `\eqref` in caption helps, and indeed it does. However this is not mentioned in the `mathtools`. Is it the right solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately `\eqref` is not a robust command, so it needs `\protect` in front of it when used in a moving argument, such as the argument of `\caption` or `\section`.

If you happen to use many times `\eqref` in such places, you can consider "robusting" it:

```
\usepackage{fixltx2e,amsmath}
\MakeRobust{\eqref}
```

Note that `\eqref` is provided by `amsmath`, rather than `mathtools` (this last package loads `amsmath`).

Comment: is there a resource that makes `robust` commands plausible? I always wonder why not all commands are robust. What are the downsides?

Comment: You use `fixltx2e` has anything changed for this answer regading the development of LaTeX/LaTeX3?

Comment: @Franz it’s no longer necessary